# Riemann Integrals proof

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working on a question involving Riemann Sums, and I'm not quite sure how to take the information I've gotten and prove an integration. The question prompts me this:

Let $f(x) = 2x +1$ on $[0,1]$

Let p be the partition $0 < 1 / n < 2 / n < · · · < n / n$.
Compute limn→∞ S¯(p) and limn→∞ S_(p)

For this I got these answers: S¯(p) = $(2j / n) + 1$ and S_(p) = $(2(j-1) / n) + 1 $.

I am then asked to use this information to prove that

$\int_{0}^{1} 2x + 1 dx = 2$.

However I am not exactly sure how to use this information to prove this. Most of the proofs I've done so far has been proving whether a function is integrable or not, not to actually prove the area of an integral. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's your j here?   You should be finding that the limit of your lower sum and your upper sum are equal,  and both are 2, thus that's the value of the integral by definition

Comment: My j is the # of the series element, i.e. the upper sum goes from j = 1 to infinity. I found the pattern to be $(2/n + 1)(1/n) + (4/n + 1)(2/n - 1/n) + (6/n + 1)(3/n - 2/n) + .... + (2j/n + 1)(n/n - (n-1)/n)$ so my answer to the upper sum was $2j/n + 1$. I see that I have to show those answers are equal to each other and they should equal 2, but I guess I can't quite grasp how I can show these answers equal 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

- $\displaystyle\mathscr{P} = \left\{ 0,\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n},\cdots,\frac{n}{n}\right\}$ be a partiton of $[0,1]$.
- $M(f;I_{k})= \sup \left\{\: f(x) \ : \ x \in I_{k}\ \right\}$
- $|I_{k}| =\text{Length of the interval $I_{k}$}$

The [Upper Riemann Sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) corresponding to $\mathscr{P}$ is defined as 
\begin{align*}
U\left(f;\mathscr{P}\right) &= \sum_{k=1}^{n} M(f;I_{k})\cdot |I_{k}|
\\&= \left( \frac{2}{n}+1\right) \cdot \frac{1}{n} + \left(\frac{4}{n}+1\right)\cdot \frac{1}{n} + \cdots + \left(\frac{2n}{n}+1 \right)\cdot \frac{1}{n}
\\ &= \frac{2}{n^{2}} \cdot (1+2+ \cdots +n) +1
\\ &= \frac{2}{n^{2}} \cdot \frac{n^{2}+n}{2} + 1
\end{align*}

Now take $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to\infty} U\left(f,\mathscr{P}\right)$ to get the answer.